# Why is Hamas holding hostage citizens from neutral countries and not promptly releasing them (or at least pledging to do so)?

Tags: terrorism, hamas, thailand, 2023-israel-hamas-war

Hamas captured 11 Thai citizens ([*Reuters* 2023-10-09](https://www.reuters.com/world/asia-pacific/thailand-working-with-other-countries-release-hostages-taken-israel-2023-10-09/), [*The Times of Israel* 2023-10-10](https://www.timesofisrael.com/my-heart-dropped-families-fear-for-thais-kidnapped-by-hamas-during-onslaught/)).

I understand that in the fog of war, Hamas may inadvertently have captured citizens from neutral countries.

I also understand that Hamas might want to hold hostage citizens from the US and other insufficiently pro-Palestinian/Hamas countries like France or Germany.

But why does Hamas hold hostage citizens from a [neutral country like Thailand](https://www.nationthailand.com/thailand/general/40031729)?

I understand that in a war, the logistics of releasing hostages might take a little work. (On 2023-10-20, Hamas released two Israeli-American hostages before any other hostages. So, it does not seem that releasing hostages is impossible.)

But why does Hamas not at least release a statement pledging to release the Thais at the earliest possible opportunity?

Hamas seems to have a pretty good public relations/social media team pumping out videos, images, and statements. So it wouldn't seem to be too much additional work to issue a statement about the fate of the captured Thai citizens.

To me, Hamas's failure to do so is foolish because it tends to confirm to many around the world or at least in Thailand that Hamas is indeed a terrorist organization.

---

The figure has now risen to 14 ([*Reuters* 2023-10-11](https://www.reuters.com/world/fourteen-thai-nationals-taken-hostage-israel-unrest-foreign-ministry-2023-10-11/)).

Now 17 ([Thai government, 2023-10-16](https://www.thaigov.go.th/news/contents/details/73390)).

Now 19 ([*Bangkok Post*, 2023-10-21](https://www.bangkokpost.com/thailand/general/2668426)).

Comment: IDK what Hamas guys are thinking, but possibly they consider those Thai agricultural workers as collaborators with the occupation. They did kill a bunch of them too.

Comment: If anything, Israeli governments of the past decade or so [actually](https://www.jpost.com/diplomacy-and-politics/thailands-recognition-of-palestine-disappointing) considered the Thai gov't positions as too pro-Palestinian, although that didn't seem to have affected the Israeli visa policies toward the Thai workers.

Comment: Voting not to close - This is a good question. And even if the answer may not be clear right now, it should be apparent soon enough when the neutral countries engage with Hamas to secure the release of the prisoners. If others are concerned that right now we will only get opinionated answers, then the right approach would be to report those answers, instead of trying to close the question itself.

Comment: May be too early to know much (which motivated the close votes).  But surely, at some point, the situation will become clearer.  What will be Hamas' position will then surely be of interest.

Answer (score 8):

FWTW, you want to know what Hamas said about this, there's a paraphrased [report](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXgpNBUuxcg) in which they say that they are ready to release the foreign, non-Israeli hostages, which were "swept up in the fighting"  but that "conditions have to be right", not amidst Israeli round-the-clock bombings.

NBC [has it](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/live-blog/israel-hamas-war-live-updates-rcna120545#rcrd21655) as:

> Hamas is willing to allow the unconditional release of foreign nationals kidnapped during its Oct. 7 attack on Israel, a spokesman for the militant group said today.
>
> Abu Abetta said in a video that Hamas did not verify their identities during the capture, but have since recognized them as foreign nationals and is treating them as guests.
>
> Hamas is treating Israelis being held captive as parties to the conflict.

There's a longer video that goes with that though, which also says that Hamas only promised to release foreigners when "field conditions are right".

Answer (score 7):

The point of terrorism is to create generalized fear; such fear is leverage against the targeted state. Offering to release citizens of neutral states would be a reasonable action that would generate good will, sure, but appearing as reasonable and good-natured would only serve to *reduce* generalized fear. That is precisely what terrorists do not want. Holding citizens of neutral states creates fear and anxiety in those states, which will turn around and put pressure on the target state to somehow resolve the issue.

Terrorism is a bit like that old apocryphal adage about going to prison: if you're not big or tough or connected then you have to convince everyone you're bat-sh!t crazy, and get what passes for respect *that* way. This is Hamas' bat-sh!t crazy moment, where they're demonstrating they have no limits unless they get what they want, where what they want is respect. Don't expect them to take the reasoning high-road.

Comment: You paint Hamas as "bat-sh!t crazy terrorists". But I don't think they see themselves that way. Nor do they want the world to see them as such. They consider themselves to be fighting a just war. I don't think they seek to kill and kidnap poor Thai migrant workers.

Comment: @user103496: It's just a word; use another if you like: e.g. partisan, freedom fighter… but the logic remains the same. A hostage is a hostage against Israel. it doesn't matter (to them, at the moment) where the hostage comes from. Israel is the host state, so Israel ends up with the responsibility. I have sympathy for the Palestinians, and I understand the rationale being use here — I'm good at the 'big picture', if you know what I mean — but it is what it is, and I'm not here to sugar-coat anything.

Comment: @user103496 How would you describe them (taking into account mass bombing of civilians, indiscriminative killing of everything that moves, capturing hostages, killing civilians while the sleep)? An insane lunatic who kills people might think he is a savior of civilization, but it does not mean he is.  Anyway, would be waiting for your description.

Comment: @SalvadorDali: They hate Israelis and Jews, and want to kill as many Israelis and Jews as possible. They do not have the same feelings for Thais.

Comment: @user103496 Are you saying indiscriminate killing of hundreds of Israeli and Jewish civilians isn't "bat-sh!t crazy" but killing one a Thai worker is?

Comment: @LioElbammalf From a purely pragmatic/realpolitik standpoint, yes that's the case.  Killing citizens of a currently-neutral third party could incite them to provide support to the enemy.  Whereas killing citizens of the country you're at war with isn't going to matter because you're already at war.

Comment: @TedWrigley I think your answer goes in the right direction. Where I think you are wrong is in saying Hamas wants to appear "crazy". It is much more consistent with their common propaganda that they want to appear enraged: an all-encompassing rage that leads them to seek retaliation without any longer making a distinction between friend or foe. "Let **everyone** feel the hurt we have felt for decades" is the sentence I have heard from supporters of Palestinian terrorism time and again. (Just to be clear: I personally think this is a despicable argument.)

Comment: I mean, one cannot call Hamas's attack precisely smart overall. Sure, they captured a bunch of hostages, whom they *might* be able to use to secure the release of some Hamas fighters. But that seems unlikely to compensate for all the people they lost in the operation, and Israel is retaliating with a heretofore unprecedented level of violence against the Gaza Strip in general, which was completely predictable and will cause more losses to them.

Comment: They also made some other terrible moves, like killing or capturing Russian or Chinese nationals. Targeting Americans might be "reasonable," since the Biden administration was always going to strongly support the Israeli response, but targeting Russian or Chinese nationals is a good way to ensure that countries that might otherwise be inclined to side with them to some extent, if only to oppose the USA, take a step back. So attacking random Thai people is not the only or largest misstep from a strategic perspective.

Comment: @ccprog: Well, I won't disagree, but I will note that they're not trying to project *mere* anger; they're trying to project irrational, uncompromising, almost psychotic anger. What I mean is, they present reasons for their anger to justify their actions, but they won't engage in reasoning about it. Their anger is presented as pure, absolute, and unquenchable. The reasons are meant to justify the crazy.

Comment: Eh. If Hamas thinks that presenting themselves as willing to attack anyone and everyone is an effective strategy, maybe they should look at the territory controlled by ISIL. Or rather, no longer controlled by ISIL, because the USA was against them; Russia was against them due to their opposition to Assad; China did not do much, if only because of what their example might have implied for some Uyghurs; and no one else really cared enough to help them.

Comment: @Obie2.0: Hamas didn't do this expecting a military victory. This was psy-ops: Hamas wanted to shame and degrade Israel, to spread fear and anger, and ultimately to provoke Israel into actions that the rest of the world would see as horrifying (which Israel promptly set about doing). They believe this will bring them political support from Palestinians and other Arab nations. The act may be deeply deluded, but it isn't precisely stupid.

Comment: OK, but it seems as if Israel has gotten even more support despite those actions, if anything, with countries like France, Germany, and the USA immediately offering their unconditional support (including military support) to an extent that they were not before. Whereas *maybe* some Arab countries may not normalize relations with Israel now, but they do not seem to be rushing to protect Palestine from the Israeli attacks, either.

Comment: @Obie2.0: Ah, me...  I've spent the last year watching the House Trump caucus smack themselves in the forehead with their own gavels, and here you are asking me to accept the concept of rational-actor terrorists. Really..? I swear, the modern political cycle seems to amount to being a total a__, claiming to be a victim when you get walloped for being a total a__, then using that victimhood to justify being an even bigger a__. I get it, but I don't pretend to understand it. The best I can say is that people *convince* themselves it makes sense, and empiricism isn't their strong suit.

Comment: This question deserves a lot better than some tired generalizations about terrorists.  Why Hamas would not release citizens from Israel-supporting countries is clear:  they would want to use them to get their respective countries to put pressure on Israel to keep their citizens safe.  But the gain with Thailand (if it is indeed neutral) is unclear and assuming that Hamas has no rationality nor method beyond inspiring fear is a good to underestimate them.  For all we know, Hamas may release them after negotiations take place, making this all the more speculative.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: Feel free to give a better answer; I would if I could, so I'm all for that. But it's easy to imagine deep planning when what we actually see is gut cunning. A lot of people just 'feel' their way through situations, jumping instinctively from this to that in the determined belief that they will reach their goal if they just… keep… moving…, like running-backs grinding and twisting their way towards the end zone. This may not have been part of the plan, until it suddenly was, and now will be until it isn't.

Comment: @LioElbammalf: *Are you saying indiscriminate killing of hundreds of Israeli and Jewish civilians isn't "bat-sh!t crazy" but killing one a Thai worker is?* Killing persons from a group one deems one's enemy and whom one hates isn't crazy (in a particular bigoted worldview). Killing and kidnapping multiple persons from a group one does not deem one's enemy and whom ones does not hate is "crazy".

Comment: @user103496 Does a "bigoted worldview" where you hate a whole race of people, regardless of their personal actions, not constitute crazy to you then? For me thats where the crazy creeps in. If not, perhaps you only have the option of believing they're secretly enemies with Thailand or Hamas is crazy (or has crazy people in positions of power, at least).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers:

Those foreign hostages put some pressure on Israel to be careful.

The IDF has repeatedly shown that human lives,  not even of Israeli citizens or IDF soldiers matter that much once captured, so their value as human shields isn't too great for Hamas. With foreign nationals however, Israel risks (further) strained  foreign relations and a drop in imported labor (something that is in need due to the loss of Palestinian laborers).

While these factors may not be that significant, I would consider those arguments.

Also Hamas has pretty much no international relations, so the cost of just not releasing them isn't too high either.